# create an env that points to a specific python installation

Tags: python, virtualenv, symlink, virtual-environment

I have a python installation with several packages linked to it that I access by calling `python2.7`. I would like to create a virtual env where I can just type `python` and access that particular installation without reinstalling everything associated with it. How would I accomplish that (virtual env, symlink, etc...) without changing my default env?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`virtualenv` allows to specify the Python executable you want to use with the `--python` (or `-p`) option, e.g.:

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 path/to/env
```

You can also use `--system-site-packages` to include the packages that are installed globally.